# Android rooting from Ubuntu

Tags: samsung, tablet, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I gather that when it comes to rooting an Android device,

1. one needs a separate machine (e.g. a desktop computer) to carry out the rooting steps from;
2. the details of the procedure depend strongly on the specific hardware of the Android device.

I want to root a Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 tablet, and pretty much all the recipes I've found online for this particular hardware work only when the second machine (the one mentioned in (1) above) is running some version of Windows.

I have not been able to find instructions specific to rooting a Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 device from Ubuntu (or Debian, etc.).

Any suggestions?

(I know that some people have managed to root an Android device from a VBox running Windows, but I'd consider this the absolute last resort, since it adds a whole new layer of complexity to the problem.)

Comment: I successfully rooted my tablet using Ubuntu.  In fact, I could not manage to do it on Windows.  I do not have suggestions specific to your device, but one thing that is different about Ubuntu is that you have to add a rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` so that your Android device can connect over USB.  In my rooting process I also had to install `adb`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried KingRoot? It looks like the only non-Odin method, but I haven't tried it.

Install KingRoot (enable external sources to install)

Run KingRoot

Tap "Try to Root"

Check success with Root Checker app (available on Google Play)

link to download:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=13663

My source:
http://trueandroid.com/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-tab-s-8-4-sm-t705-without-pc/
Here's some extra info on it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/one-click-root-tool-android-2-x-5-0-t3107461